# How to use generics to create a thread class that returns different values

Tags: multithreading, delphi, generics, delphi-2009

I admit it, I am learning a lot from Stack Overflow.

After [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136530/how-to-manage-the-return-value-of-a-thread/4137586#4137586) I understood how to make a decoupled background Thread class that returns an integer I am now wondering how to make it more generic.

But how do I need to change this (where "integer" is hardcoded). I use a very long classname just for demonastrating purposes:

```
type
  TSyncMethod = Procedure(ThreadResult: integer) of Object;
  TBackgroundThreadWithIntegerResult = class(TThread)
  private
    FResult: integer;
```

to the generic counterpart?

Comment: Small note: This is bad design. Why would you want to create a new thread class only because the result type of your worker code has changed? The use of `TThread` is an implementation detail here, so you should choose composition over inheritance. Create a generic class that computes the result, and make it possible to execute this either in the calling thread, or in a dedicated thread, or in a thread from a pool.

Comment: Of course TBackGroundThreadWithIntegerResult is not the best soution, this is why I am thinking of using generics. In this way I don't need to add a subclass of TThread for every type of result. The fact is that the results is always related to a DB query, sometimes it can return an integer, sometimes a string, sometimes a TDataSet. So what the thread does is simply to execute a query and save to the result an integer, a string or a TDataSet. Anyway how to assign the result according to the generic T type it is not clear to me and this is what I asked as a comment to Jens Mühlenhoff's answe.

Comment: @mghie ok, but since I need to return a generic value how do I handle the generic calculation class inside the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type
  TBackgroundThreadWithGenericResult<T> = class(TThread)
  private
    FResult: T;
  public
    type
      TSyncMethod = Procedure(ThreadResult: T) of Object;
```

Of course you can choose a more elaborate type name then `T` for your generic type. I have put the `TSyncMethod` into the class for simplicity.

Usage would be `TBackgroundThreadWithGenericResult<Integer>.Create(...)`.

Comment: ok thanks. I see that it works also if TsyncMethod is inside the class. I have one question: how do I handle the Result type? In the non generic example it was the result of a query: FResult :=  FData.Query.Fields[0].asinteger; ... how does this translate in the generic version? I mean for every <T> how do I set the result in a generic way?

Comment: @user193655: That is a bit more tricky, I would probably not use generics in this case and return `FData.Query.Fields[0].Value` (assuming Query is a TDataSet descendant) as a `Variant`.

Comment: But If I need to return also a TDataset this will not be possible with variants. An alternative is to return TDataSet only, so in case of an integer I will extract the integer from the field. Anyway this forces to handle a dataset even when it would only need an integer. Can you suggest another approach?

Comment: Just for clarity, I want to have 3 options: return an integer, a string a TDataset Object.

Comment: Well you *can* use a Variant to return a TDataSet object. Add a `Mode` property to the class and decide what to put into the `FResult: Variant`.